# what does mean about battery_level in event log

Tags: android

I got a event log information

**I/battery_level( 1147): [0,3200,420]**

I look up event-log-tags and find:

**2722 battery_level (level|1|6),(voltage|1|1),(temperature|1|1)**

I find the follow information in the file for the format.

**Optionally, after the tag names can be put a description for the value(s) of the tag.**

**Description are in the format**

```
(<name>|data type[|data unit])
```

Multiple values are separated by commas.

The data type is a number from the following values:

1: int

2: long

3: string

4: list

The data unit is a number taken from the following list:

1: Number of objects

2: Number of bytes

3: Number of milliseconds

4: Number of allocations

5: Id

6: Percent

*So my question is who know the means about the temperature value and explain to me the real information?*

Form my log information, we know the temperature is a int type and the value is number of objects. I totally miss understand the means about the value, 420. I can assertion 420 isn't Fahrenheit/Celsius temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

420 could be *anything*.

It could be 42.0 F (which seems unlikely)

It could be 42.0 C (which seems likely)

It could be 4.20 F (really unlikely)

It could be 4.20 C (also unlikely)

It could be some kind of scaled factor.  For instance a thermistor could respond with values between 0 and 512 over some range of temperatures.  For example a zero could be 21 F and 512 could be 154F.  Or 512 could mean 38F and 0 could mean 123F.

You can't know without a lot more information from the manufacturer and the software developer.  You certainly can't guess.